# Subarray with range

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to split an array of objects into smaller arrays containing 32 objects. With the remaining about being put into the array at the end.

This is the code I'm using

```
int a = sharedManager.inventoryArray2.count;
float b = a / 33;
int c = ceilf(b);

NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays = [NSMutableArray array];
int from = 0;
int to = 31;

for (int e = 0; e <= c; e++) {

    if (sharedManager.inventoryArray2.count < to) {

       NSArray *smallArray = [sharedManager.inventoryArray2 subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(from, sharedManager.inventoryArray2.count)]; 
        [arrayOfArrays addObject:smallArray];
    }
    else {
       NSArray *smallArray = [sharedManager.inventoryArray2 subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(from, to)];
       from = from + (31+1);
       to = from + 31;
       [arrayOfArrays addObject:smallArray];
    } 
}
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: range {32, 63} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 83]'
```

I don't get it, the range of 32-63 is in the bounds of 0-83.

Any advice?

Thanks.
Paul.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A NSRange indicates the starting point and the number of entries to select from that point on.. So it actually means "Starting point 32, select 63 items from that point on", which will exceed your 83 entries (32 **+** 63)

Comment: aha, thank you. maybe i should read the documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

2nd parameter of NSMakeRange is length range to create, not the last index in it. So you need to change your code accordingly (simplifying it a bit):

```
NSUInteger count = sharedManager.inventoryArray2.count;
NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger from = 0;
while (from < count) {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(from, MIN(32, count-from));
    NSArray *smallArray = [sharedManager.inventoryArray2 subarrayWithRange:range];
    [arrayOfArrays addObject:smallArray];

    from += 32;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No Actually the range doesn't work like this 
NSRange {32, 63} => means from the index 32 take 63 elements

Here is documentation :

```
NSRange

A structure used to describe a portion of a series—such as characters in a string or objects in an NSArray object.

typedef struct _NSRange {
  NSUInteger location;
  NSUInteger length;
 } NSRange;

 location
The start index (0 is the first, as in C arrays). For type compatibility with the rest of the system, LONG_MAX is the maximum value you should use for location.

 length
The number of items in the range (can be 0). For type compatibility with the rest of the system, LONG_MAX is the maximum value you should use for length.
```